# Formal approach to choosing between "there is" and "there are"

Tags: grammaticality

Consider:

> There (is/are) a banana and two oranges?
>   There (is/are) two oranges and a banana?

I'm looking for a non-colloquial and formally correct way (British English) of writing these two sentences if there is any. Any references are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It's either "There is a banana and two oranges." or "There are two oranges and a banana."

Reference: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv128.shtml

Comment: +1: But I think there may be exceptions. I'd say *"there are a cat and a dog who fight all the time living in the house next door",* because this sentence treats the cat and dog together as a unit. (Of course, this might be idiosyncratic or it might be my American dialect; I'd like to know if somebody has investigated this.)

Comment: @ Peter Shor:  I'd say "There are a cat and a dog who fight all the time living in the house next door", because this sentence treats the cat and dog together as a unit, too. I'd also say "There are a banana and two oranges in the bowl." (I might swap them round if I didn't fancy an argument.) But "There is bacon and eggs on the menu."

Comment: At https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/ is: << **9.** In sentences beginning with 'there is' or 'there are', the subject follows the verb. Since _there_ is not the subject, the verb agrees with what follows.

There are many questions.
There is a question.>> Combining this with the undisputed 'John and Jane are here' gives "There are a banana and two oranges." I'm adding this becaues it supports the way I'd do it, not because I believe my quoted authority is necessarily superior to Zafer's.

Comment: @Edwin: I agree that the only truly unacceptable grammar here is "There is two oranges and a banana ...". If the banana's first, I'm happy with either verb.

Comment: @Peter Shor: It's high time the English language was overhauled by mathematicians. Of course, that would leave us nothing to agonise over. _In our dreams._ (... Now which sentence does that comment refer back to?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Surely you meant to write “It’s high time the English language ***were*** overhauled by mathematicians.”

Comment: @tchrist: Maybe he's anticipating the first step in the overhaul: eliminate the subjunctive?

Answer (score 0):

In school we learn to:

1. Use the noun nearest to the verb when using

   - either... or...
   - neither... nor...
   - not only... but also...
   - not... but...

(They are before each noun)

1. Use the first noun when using

   - ...together with...
   - ...like...
   - ...including...
   - ...as well as...

(They are in the middle)

Comment: But this construction is "There is/are ... and ..."; it's not on your list.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to respond... it is not about the "there", it's about the connector between the nouns: Use no. 2 for "...and..." (I forgot to add it). "There are seven bananas and a monkey." and "There is a monkey and seven bananas." I will check this with a teacher tomorrow.